# How do I unit-test a meteor application?

Tags: unit-testing, meteor

What's Meteor's story with respect to unit testing?

The example videos look great for building prototypes but I haven't seen any indication of how to write tests for it.

Answer (score 1):

For testing meteor packages, see [Tinytest](http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-testing-packages-with-tinytest).

The [testing story](https://trello.com/c/BQ3gu0no/12-official-testing-framework) as a whole is captured on the official Trello board.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at documentation of Laika testing framework :
http://arunoda.github.io/laika/

Screencast with introduction to Laika done by its creator - Arunoda Susiripal:
http://www.discovermeteor.com/2013/06/06/testing-meteor-apps-with-laika

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you would use `velocity` + `jasmine-unit` packages.

Velocity had been selected as the official testing framework for meteor 1.0. The announcement has been made in the [last meteor devshop (june 2014)](http://youtu.be/kwFv1mXrLWE?t=40m50s).

Packages developed with velocity:

- [velocity](https://atmospherejs.com/package/velocity) (the test runner)
- [jasmine-unit](https://atmospherejs.com/package/jasmine-unit) (jasmine syntax)
- [mocha-web-velocity](https://atmospherejs.com/package/mocha-web-velocity) (for testing collections)
- [velocity-html-reporter](https://atmospherejs.com/package/velocity-html-reporter) (view the tests in the browser)

Answer (score 0):

About the usage of tinytest, once you have watched the screencast proposed by Jeff Foster, and understood the idea, you may want to take a look at the APIS of both `tinytest` and `test-helpers` packages.

For now the only documentation available for `tinytest` is at the bottom of the tinytest.js file
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/tinytest/tinytest.js

The list of the helpers made available by the `test-helpers` package can be looked at here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/test-helpers. There often is some documentation inside each file.

Digging in the existing tests of meteor's packages will provide lot of examples. One way of doing this is to make a search for `Tinytest.` or `test.` in the package directory of meteor's source code